# Call service on injected module

Tags: angularjs

I have a `main module` and some `submodules`. I am injecting the `submodules` in the `mainmodule`. Now I want to access a service of the `submodule - how do I do that?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'AuthenticationModule',
]);

myApp.controller('TestController', function($scope, 'AuthenticationModule') {
        /* How do I use the service? */
        $scope.testVar = AuthenticationModule.SERVICE?????
});
```

And the `submodule`

```
var AuthenticationModule = angular.module('AuthenticationModule', []);

AuthenticationModule.service('TestService', function() {
    this.testFunction = function() {
        return 'You successfully got me!';
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular, you do not inject `modules`. Instead, you declare the dependencies among modules and then all the `controllers`, `services`, `directives` and `values` from the dependencies are available in the application module.

How you would do it in your case is most likely this:

```js
var AuthenticationModule = angular.module('AuthenticationModule', []);

AuthenticationModule.service('TestService', function() {
    this.testFunction = function() {
        return 'You successfully got me!';
    };
});

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'AuthenticationModule',
]);

myApp.controller('TestController', function($scope, 'TestService') {
        /* Injected the "TestService" directly */
        $scope.testVar = TestService.testFunction();
});
```

Comment: @lanoxx Providers are available only during the `config` phase of initializing the app and not in the controllers/services/directives the app is using.